# INSERT statement has UK date format, but Access inserts it as US

Tags: date, ms-access, vb6, format

I'm trying to insert dates into an `Ms-Access` database (Access 2003) using this code

```
qtyPrice.code = cmbStock.Text
qtyPrice.desc = txtDescription.Text
qtyPrice.group = cmbGroup.Text
qtyPrice.qty = CDbl(Grd_Pricing.Columns(0).CellText(bm))
qtyPrice.price = CCur(Grd_Pricing.Columns(1).CellText(bm))
qtyPrice.qDate = CDate(Grd_Pricing.Columns(2).CellText(bm))



SQL = "INSERT INTO [stockQuantities] ([stockCode], [description], [productGroup], " & _
      "[qtyFrom], [price], [dateQuoted]) " & _
       "VALUES (" & sqlString(qtyPrice.code) & ", sqlString(qtyPrice.desc) & _
       ", " & sqlString(qtyPrice.group) & ", " & CDbl(qtyPrice.qty) & _
       ", " & qtyPrice.price & ", #" & qtyPrice.qDate & "#);"
```

When debugging, this SQL statements read

> INSERT INTO [stockQuantities] ([stockCode], [description], [productGroup], [qtyFrom], [price], [dateQuoted]) VALUES ("010010000", "R&B BOT Gl Etched 100ml Temple Spa Logo", "PACK", 100, 98, #07/01/2019#);

With the date showing as 7th January 2019.

However, once it gets inserted, Access stores it as 01/07 (1st July)

How can I change this? I have tried adding `Format(qtyPrice.dateQuoted, "dd/MM/yyyy")` to both the SQL statement and the property assignment, but it was the same result.

Comment: Try this `Format(qtyPrice.dateQuoted, "yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: @Santosh that seems to have done it - what's different with this that makes it work?

Comment: Its the international format defined by ISO

Comment: @Harambe  Although the suggested change works, the explanation is not complete.  The "difference" is more complicated and also has to do with localization settings of the operating system, which Access uses to interpret string dates.  Specifying the date format inside the Format() function call had nothing to do with how Access interpreted the embedded date string value in the SQL.  Said another way, the Format() does not inform Access or the SQL engine about the intended format of the numbers.  The Format function just spits out a string which is left for later interpretation.

Comment: @Harambe  It just turns out that placing the 4-digit year first signaled to the SQL parser and interpreter that standard interpretation of that format is the year, followed by the month, followed by the day.  Although "mm/dd/yyyy" and "dd/mm/yyyy" are common orders of date values, I do not think that "yyyy-dd-mm" is ever an accepted order of values, so the format "yyyy-mm-dd" removed all ambiguity and was not dependent upon the localized date format.

Comment: I can't find any evidence to suggest that this works due to anything but luck, that luck being how OLE's date parsing heuristics pachinko machine falls when processing invalid syntax.  All of the Jet documentation I have specifies the use of Invariant Locale syntax (i.e. U.S. English).  But even better: use a parameter query and pass a Date type value instead of cobbling up dynamic SQL in the first place.  I suspect that the "ISO" format is just an urban legend that arose because it works much of the time.

Comment: Ok, further testing suggests that yyyy-dd-mm is *not* accepted by the OLE parser (which Jet SQL uses).  That would mean that the ISO format should always work.  Maybe somebody can find a link documenting this?